# Can I send money to indian saving account from Canada bank account?

Tags: income-tax, india, money-transfer, international-transfer, foreign-income

I am confused about how to send money from Canada bank account to my Indian Saving account since I came to Canada only for work assignment for 1 year.

I came to Canada in November,2018 and moving back to India in November ,2019.

I didn't open NRE or NRO account.

So can someone confirm me if I'll send money through Xoom and remitly to my India saving account, will it be fine or I'll get issue in tax filing in India ? Or will receive any notice from indian bank or income tax department ?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to open NRE account.

Comment: Consult a tax expert.  You may not need NRE/NRO since India did sign DTAA with Canada to tackle double taxation, otherwise, nobody is willing to bring money back to their home country.  You must be able to produce your Canada tax declaration document, to prove that you are not laundering money for others.

Comment: Thanks @mootmoot.yes I have my salary slips and even transfer records bas well from remitly.

Comment: @Dheer : I am moving back to India. Canada didn't impress me like I heard when I was in India.

Answer (score 1):

> can someone confirm me if I'll send money through Xoom and remitly to my India saving account, will it be fine or I'll get issue in tax filing in India ? Or will receive any notice from indian bank or income tax department ?

You can transfer to savings account. You may get an enquiry from tax authorities. You have to evidence that the income is during your status as NRI. Taxes are not applicable in India.

Comment: Great ..thanks. I'll go ahead and will transfer all my money to Indian account before I move to India.